# What is the equivalent for depends_on in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

I have a docker compose file with the following entries

---

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  mysql:
    container_name: mysql 
    image: mysql:latest 
    volumes:
      - ./mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql 
    environment: 
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password' 
    ports: 
      - '3306:3306' 
    healthcheck: 
        test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:3306"] 
        interval: 30s 
        timeout: 10s 
        retries: 5 

  test1: 
    container_name: test1 
    image: test1:latest 
    ports: 
      - '4884:4884' 
      - '8443' 
    depends_on: 
      mysql: 
        condition: service_healthy 
    links: 
     - mysql
```

The Test-1 container is dependent on mysql and it needs to be up and running.

In docker this can be controlled using health check and depends_on attributes. 
The health check equivalent in kubernetes is readinessprobe which i have already created but how do we control the container startup in the pod's?????

Any directions on this is greatly appreciated.

My Kubernetes file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata: 
  name: deployment 
spec: 
  replicas: 1 
  template: 
    metadata: 
      labels: 
        app: deployment 

    spec: 
      containers: 
      - name: mysqldb 
        image: "dockerregistry:mysqldatabase" 
        imagePullPolicy: Always 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 3306 
        readinessProbe: 
          tcpSocket: 
            port: 3306 
          initialDelaySeconds: 15 
          periodSeconds: 10 
      - name: test1 
        image: "dockerregistry::test1" 
        imagePullPolicy: Always 
        ports: 
        - containerPort: 3000
```

Comment: The issue primarily seems to be one of tool expectations.  Using docker and K8s is intended to be for containerized microservices, which is designed differently than a single stand-alone app or a purely Ansible/etc-managed system.  You're trying to use it like an Ansible playbook. Properly, K8s would have you define the database service which sets itself up and runs independently from the app Service using it.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This was purposefully left out. The reason being is that applications should be responsible for their connect/re-connect logic for connecting to service(s) such as a database. This is outside the scope of Kubernetes.

Comment: initContainers are as close as equivalent you can get to dependsOn, so mentioning initContainers is a better solution.

Comment: `depends_on` equivalent is intentionally left out, but initContainers is legit. Design logic seems kind of arbitrary.

Comment: Every service manager provides this, Kubernetes will eventually have to if we complain enough.

Comment: `initContianers` covers pretty much the only valid use for `depends_on`, waiting on a bunch of services to start up before you run your app.  But it also supports handling any arbitrary first-time-startup logic for your app container (like database init) that shouldn't be re-run if the app has to restart.  What isn't covered in K8s is the poor app design of assuming all your dependent services are always available once started.  If you have a chain of services that need restarting if any one of them crashes, you have an app/service design problem.

Comment: " If you have a chain of services that need restarting if any one of them crashes, you have an app/service design problem." - I believe this is real logic behind K8 not choose to take care of its dependency chain lifecycle.  as @mtalexan has mentioned above.

Comment: @spinkus "depends_on" means AppA explicitly tells/reminds itself that Before A - its dependencies B and C needs to be configured by "docker-compose" and this list of dependencies can change.
while having "init-containers" just want to do DAY0 setup and just once in AppA lifecycle is not same as taking care of dependencies because init-containers is for just once and "depends-on" is like for each time.

Comment: @yomateo can you provide source?

Answer (score 55):

That's the beauty of Docker Compose and Docker Swarm... Their simplicity.

We came across this same Kubernetes shortcoming when deploying the ELK stack.
We solved it by using a side-car (initContainer), which is just another container in the same pod thats run first, and when it's complete, kubernetes automatically starts the [main] container. We made it a simple shell script that is in loop until Elasticsearch is up and running, then it exits and Kibana's container starts.

Below is an example of a side-car that waits until Grafana is ready.

Add this 'initContainer' block just above your other containers in the Pod:

```
spec:
      initContainers:
      - name: wait-for-grafana
        image: darthcabs/tiny-tools:1
        args:
        - /bin/bash
        - -c
        - >
          set -x;
          while [[ "$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w ''%{http_code}'' http://grafana:3000/login)" != "200" ]]; do 
            echo '.'
            sleep 15;
          done
      containers:
          .
          .
  (your other containers)
          .
          .
```

Comment: how about timeout for wait? example more 10 minutes is brakes?

Comment: what if all the elasticsearch and kibana pods are down?

Comment: In other words, you had to implement it yourself

Comment: Just FYI though, the initContainers only run as one-shot containers when you first start the pod.  Unless you manually shut down the pod and then bring it back up, they won't run again.  https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

Answer (score 10):

While I don't know the direct answer to your question except [this link (k8s-AppController)](https://github.com/Mirantis/k8s-AppController), I don't think it's wise to use same deployment for DB and app. Because you are tightly coupling your db with app and loosing awesome k8s option to scale any one of them as needed. Further more if your db pod dies you loose your data as well.

Personally what I would do is to have a separate [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) with [Persistent Volume](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) for database and Deployment for app and use [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) to make sure their communication.
Yes I have to run few different commands and may need at least two separate deployment files but this way I am decoupling them and can scale them as needed. And my data is being persistent as well!

Comment: `Because you are tightly coupling your db with app` this depends on the application you are developing, if it's a small application is much more work to `uncouple` and usually not needed

Answer (score 7):

As mentioned, you should run the database and the application containers in separate pods and connect them with a service.

Unfortunately, both Kubernetes and Helm don't provide a functionality similar to what you've described. We had many issues with that and tried a few approaches until we have decided to develop a smallish utility that solved this problem for us.

Here's the link to the tool we've developed: https://github.com/Opsfleet/depends-on

You can make pods wait until other pods become ready according to their readinessProbe configuration. It's very close to Docker's depends_on functionality.

Answer (score 3):

In Kubernetes terminology one your docker-compose set is a [Pod](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/#what-is-a-pod).

So, there is no `depends_on` equivalent there. Kubernetes will check all containers in a pod and they all have to be alive for a mark that pod as Healthy and will always run them together.

In your case, you need to prepare configuration of Deployment like that:

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 kind: Deployment
 metadata:
   name: my-app
 spec:
   replicas: 1
   template:
     metadata:
       labels:
         app: app-and-db
     spec:
       containers:
         - name: app
           image: nginx
           ports:
             - containerPort: 80
         - name: db
           image: mysql
           ports:
             - containerPort: 3306
```

After pod will be started, your database will be available on `localhost` interface for your application, because of [network conception](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod/):

> Containers within a pod share an IP address and port space, and can find each other via localhost. They can also communicate with each other using standard inter-process communications like SystemV semaphores or POSIX shared memory.

But, as @leninhasda mentioned, it is not a good idea to run database and application in your pod and without Persistent Volume. Here is a good tutorial on how to run a [stateful application in the Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/run-single-instance-stateful-application/).

Comment: This answer isn't correct.  The docker compose as written will run every container in a separate pod.  Only very recently has docker and docker compose started exposing the capability to use multi-container pods, and that syntax isn't present here.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a 1:1 direct replacement for `depends_on` but you can get really close using `InitContainers` and `nc` (netcat).

The problem I have with David Cardoso's answer is it depends on the image `darthcabs/tiny-tools:1` and I would rather use `busybox`. However busybox **does not come with cURL** and the implementation of `wget` it ships with has long-running TLS termination bugs with self-signed certificates, so I don't consider it reliable as of Q1 2024.

What are we left with? We can use `netcat` to check for open ports in the container we want to "depend on" which will get us as close to `depends_on` as possible with minimal dependencies. Here is what I am using in my prod stack:

```
spec:
  initContainers:
    - name: wait-for-services
      image: busybox
      command: ["/bin/sh","-c"]
      args: ["until echo 'Waiting for postgres...' && nc -vz -w 2 postgres 5432 && echo 'Waiting for minio...' && nc -vz -w 2 minio 9000; do echo 'Looping forever...'; sleep 2; done;"]
```

What this does:

1. InitContainer starts before the main container (*handled by Kubernetes*)
2. `until` allows us to loop forever, until all the chained commands run successfully
3. `nc -vz -w 2 <service> <port>` runs `netcat` (nc) with a 2 second timeout (`-w 2`), verbose output (`-v`),  and listens for an open socket only, then disconnects (`-z`).
4. **If the netcat connection to postgres is successful**, then we continue down the command chain, attempting to connect to minio. All the `echo` commands are purely for log transparency and can be removed.
5. After both connections are successful, the InitContainer exits and kubernetes will start the main container (*handled by Kubernetes*).

---

Feel free to improve my answer as I cobbled this together from many separate sources, but it works in my prod stack. Keep in mind this is **not a replacement for Readiness or Liveness probes**, those are still needed to determine if a pod is healthy. This solution only fills the gap of `depends_on` not existing in Kubernetes.

If you need to check the `response code` of the TCP connection, for example `200 OK` of a healthcheck endpoint, you will want to use cURL instead: https://varlogdiego.com/tag/init-container

If the service you are depending on doesn't have a TCP service you can connect to, then it's a bit more difficult. You will need to share a volume between the InitContainer and the dependent service and check that a shared file has been written to the disk, or you can implement a healthcheck into the dependent service itself, such as gRPC.

Answer (score -2):

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/

what about liveness and readiness ??? supports commands, http requests and more to check if another service responds OK

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  labels:
    test: liveness
  name: liveness-exec
spec:
  containers:
  - name: liveness
    image: k8s.gcr.io/busybox
    args:
    - /bin/sh
    - -c
    - touch /tmp/healthy; sleep 30; rm -rf /tmp/healthy; sleep 600
    livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command:
        - curl http://service2/api/v2/health-check
      initialDelaySeconds: 5
      periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: The probes expose to K8s the state of the containers, but do nothing to link that state to any actions.  Theoretically you could write your own code for startup that would externally connect to the K8s and watch the lifecycle status of specific containers before starting subsequent ones, but that's an entire external application to replace the one-line `depends_on` statement in the docker compose.